# How to call rest api PUT request with adding single value in header and json data in body in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.android, http-headers

Rest API is written and I have a URL of one method. I just want to hit that URL and add single key value pair in header, and json data in body. This is what I have done so far:

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("authorization");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", "Token "+base64token);

    var content = new StringContent(JsonString, Encoding.UTF8, 
                  "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(queryString, content);
```

Here uri= My base url, base64token= authorization token, JsonString= Json data for body, queryString= path of method called.
Now, problem is that this method works for the first time correctly for user1. But does'nt works for user2. And when I call again for user1, it is still working for user1. Kindly help

Comment: looks like authentication issue. Are you sure, that "Authorization" header from first request (user1) is differ from second (user2)? What if you at first try to invoke request as user2 and then as user1?

Comment: user1: OTZkMGUxNGUtOGE0Yi00OGM5LTlkY2YtNzdmZDEyN2JjNGI2
user2: ZTY0M2MxYjMtZjkwNC00MTcxLWFjMDEtMGJkYTNkOWJlZTc0

These are the two authorization tokens and they are different.
It does'nt matter which I invoke first, for user1 invokes correctly but user2 does not.

Comment: @vasily.sib I think this line has some issue...............................................................
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("authorization");
it is not removing the previous header. Because first time I invoke for user1, so token might be saved in header since the first time.

Comment: No, because you instantiating new `HttpClient` instance two lines before

Comment: also "It does'nt matter which you invoke first", so it is diffinetly an error in user2 token

Comment: That means I don't need to remove header in this code. 
token is absolutely fine because i am also calling other Rest calls using this token and they are working fine.

Comment: if you are sure, that token is fine, then it is a server-side issue. Can you show what is server response for this request (as user2)? HTTP status code? Error message?

Comment: @SharjeelMalik show the actual usage of the http client when making the calls for the different users in a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. This will help us to better identify the problem and a possible solution.

Comment: @SharjeelMalik also "not work" is way to broad of a statement. What was the expected and actual behavior when the above was executed. was there a response code, an exception....etc?